# removing duplicates from a list and combining it in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp

I have a following type of list

```
(("abc" "12" "45")
 ("abc" "34" "56")
 ("cdb" "56" "78")
 ("deg" "90" "67")
 ("deg" "45" "34"))
```

and desired output is

```
(("abc" "12" "45" "34" "56")
 ("cdb" "56" "78")
 ("deg" "90" "67" "45 "34)).
```

What is the right approach for the same in Lisp?

Comment: The approach that you take in Lisp won't be _too_ much different from the way that you'd solve it in another language.  What have you tried so far?  What approach would you take if you were working in another language that you're familiar with?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the task is?  For instance, in the data you've shown, the first list is already sorted alphabetically by the first elements of the lists.  Is that a guarantee?  Removing duplicates from sorted lists is much easier than removing duplicates from unsorted lists.  Are the "merged" elements supposed to keep those remaining elements in alphabetical order?  In the order that they appeared in the original lists?  Should duplicates be removed from them?  As it stands now, the problem is under-specified.

Answer (score 3):

In Common Lisp, one possibility is something like this:

```
(defun merge-lists (lists)
  (let ((rv (make-hash-table :test #'equal)))
         (mapcar (lambda (list)
           (mapcar (lambda (x) (push x (gethash (car list) rv nil))) (cdr list)))
                   lists)
    (loop for key being the hash-keys of rv
          collect (cons key (reverse (gethash key rv))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great answers on this this thread already.  But since no one
has mentioned Common Lisp set operations I thought I'd pipe in with my
own.

Assuming that you're data really looks like this:

```
'((("abc") ("12" "45"))
  (("abc") ("34" "56"))
  (("cdb") ("56" "78"))
  (("deg") ("90" "67"))
  (("deg") ("45" "34")))
```

,i.e. a table of a key paired with a sequence of values. And that what you want is to merge the values of a given key, not just
append them, then Common Lisp has has a straight forward series of
operations to do that.  Just use `assoc` and `union`.  Note, union works as follows:

```
(setf record1 '("abc" "12" "34" "56"))
(setf record2 ' ("abc" "56" "45" "43"))
(union (cdr record1) (cdr record2) :test #'string=)

=> ("34" "12" "56" "45" "43")
```

`assoc` allows you to build key value tables from a list of lists. You can add a couple of access functions to abstract away the underlying representation as follows:

```
(defun get-record (table key)
  (assoc key table :test #'string=))

(defun merge-records (record1 record2)
  (if (not record1) 
      record2
          (cons (car record1) 
        (union (cdr record1) (cdr record2) :test #'string=))))

(defun insert-record (table record)
  (cons (merge-records record (get-record table (car record))) table))
```

So, using your test data:

```
(setf raw-data '(("abc" "12" "45")
    ("abc" "34" "56")
    ("abc" "45" "43")  ;; Note, duplicate value 45 to illustrate usage of union.
    ("cdb" "56" "78")
    ("deg" "90" "67")
    ("deg" "45" "34")))
```

load data into the table:

```
(setf data-table (reduce  #'insert-record raw-data :initial-value '()))
```

print the table:

```
(mapcar (lambda (key) (get-record data-table key)) '("abc" "cdb" "deg"))

==> (("abc" "12" "34" "56" "45" "43") ("cdb" "78" "56") ("deg" "34" "45" "67" "90"))
```

Of course alists are not very efficient, either for our insertion or for looking up values.  But they're super convenient to use, so a typical workflow would be to develop your solution using an alist solution, abstracting the actual implementation through access functions, and then, once you've clarified your understanding of the problem and firmed up your implementation, choose a more efficient data structure -- if it would make a difference in real-world performance, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In Racket, which is a dialect of Scheme, which in turn is a dialect of Lisp, you can solve this problem by using a hash table to keep track of the repeated elements between lists with the same first element, using the first element as key, accumulating the result by means of a fold operation, and finally mapping over the key/value pairs consing the keys with their list values. Here's how:

```
(define input
  '(("abc" "12" "45") ("abc" "34" "56") ("cdb" "56" "78")
    ("deg" "90" "67") ("deg" "45" "34")))

(hash-map
 (foldl (lambda (e h)
          (hash-update h (car e)
                       (lambda (p) (append (cdr e) p))
                       (const '())))
        (make-immutable-hash)
        input)
 cons)
```

The result is as expected, although the elements in the merged list appear in a different order (but this shouldn't be a problem, and if the need arises, sorting them is trivial):

```
'(("deg" "45" "34" "90" "67") ("abc" "34" "56" "12" "45") ("cdb" "56" "78"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp a brute force solution using sorting and tail recursion could be:

```
(defun combine-duplicates (list)
  (labels ((rec (tail marker accum result)
             (cond ((not tail)
                    (append result (list accum)))
                   ((equal marker (caar tail))
                    (rec (cdr tail)  marker (append accum (cdar tail)) result))
                   (t
                    (rec (cdr tail) (caar tail) (car tail) (append result (list accum)))))))
    (if (not list) nil
        (let ((sorted-list (sort list #'string-lessp :key #'car)))
          (rec (cdr sorted-list) (caar sorted-list) (car sorted-list) nil)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem, as stated, has the input already sorted by the first element, here's a solution that takes advantage of that fact. It makes just one pass over the input list, building up the result list in reverse order, and returned the (`nreverse`d) result.

```
(defparameter *input* 
  '(("abc" "12" "45")
    ("abc" "34" "56")
    ("cdb" "56" "78")
    ("deg" "90" "67")
    ("deg" "45" "34")))

(defparameter *desired-output* 
  '(("abc" "12" "45" "34" "56")
    ("cdb" "56" "78")
    ("deg" "90" "67" "45" "34")))

(defun merge-duplicates (input) 
  ;; Start with the result being empty, and continue until there are
  ;; no more sublists in the input to process.  Since the result is
  ;; built up in reverse order, it is NREVERSEd for return.
  (do ((result '()))
      ((endp input) (nreverse result))
    ;; Each element from the input can be popped off, and should have
    ;; the form (key . elements).  
    (destructuring-bind (key &rest elements) (pop input)
      ;; The result list (except in the first iteration) has the form
      ;; ((key-x . elements-x) ...), so we check whether key is equal
      ;; to key-x.
      (if (equal key (first (first result)))
          ;; If it is, then replace elements-x with (append
          ;; elements-x elements).  (This keeps the merged lists in
          ;; order.  This is a bit wasteful; we could record all
          ;; these elements during traversal and only concatenate
          ;; once at the end, but it would complicate the return form
          ;; a bit.
          (setf (rest (first result))
                (append (rest (first result)) elements))
          ;; Otherwise, they're different, and we can just push (key
          ;; . elements) into the result list, since it marks the
          ;; beginning of a new sublist.  Since we destructively
          ;; update the tails, we do not want to put the cons from
          ;; the input into results, so we make a copy using (list*
          ;; key elements) (which is EQUAL to the thing we popped
          ;; from input.
          (push (list* key elements)
                result)))))
```

Here's an example of it in action, along with a test to make sure that it's returning a correct result:

```
CL-USER> (problem *input*)
(("abc" "12" "45" "34" "56") ("cdb" "56" "78") ("deg" "90" "67" "45" "34"))

CL-USER> (equal (problem *input*) *desired-output*)
T
```

It will fail if the input has the form `((nil ...) ...)`, since `result` is initially `nil` and `(first (first result))` will return `nil`, so `(equal key (first (first result)))` will be true, and the `(setf (rest (rest ...)) ...)` will try to access a non-`setf`able place.  It's also a bit wasteful in creating the merged tails, but it was never specified what the order of those elements should be, so this at least tries to keep them in that same order.

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp again but neither fastest nor shortest.  You could elide `copy-list` and munge the original but then it could produce circular lists given shared structure.  The TEST keyword has the canonical default.

```
(defun fixup-alist (old &key (test #'eql))
  "Combine OLD alist's duplicate keys."
  (let ((new (mapcar #'list
                     (delete-duplicates (mapcar #'car old)
                                        :test test))))
    (dolist (entry old new)
      (nconc (assoc (car entry) new
                    :test test)
             (copy-list (cdr entry))))))
FIXUP-ALIST
CL-USER> (fixup-alist x)
(("abc" "12" "45") ("abc" "34" "56") ("cdb" "56" "78") ("deg" "90" "67") ("deg" "45" "34"))
CL-USER> (fixup-alist x :test #'string=)
(("abc" "12" "45" "34" "56") ("cdb" "56" "78") ("deg" "90" "67" "45" "34"))
```